# Ordre des éléments : « la voix montait, de Letondu » (Messieurs les Ronds-de-Cuir, Georges Courteline)

Tags: syntaxe, stylistique

> De là-bas, tout là-bas, comme du fond d’un puits, la voix montait, de
> Letondu parti à pérorer tout seul et discourant touchant les turpitudes
> humaines.

Cette phrase s'écrirait de nos jours naturellement « … montait la voix de Letondu parti à pérorer… ».

Je suppose que l'ordre chez Courteline est une question de style plutôt que de syntaxe, et quelqu'un pourra peut-être remédier à la lacune que cette incertitude implique, mais qu'il s'agisse de l'un ou de l'autre, il serait intéressant de savoir si, disons ce style, est préférable de nos jours ou bien s'il a été relégué au oubliettes des tours démodés, ou qui ne seraient peut-être pas tant démodés que considérés de nos jours lourds ou gauches.

Évidemment, je me rends compte que c'est une question difficile ; une réponse sérieuse me semble devoir entraîner beaucoup de recherche, mais peut-être quelqu'un est en possession de quelque information intéressante à ce sujet.

Comment: Je dirais, *opinion based*. Le style est une affaire de goût. Il n'existe pas de *style préférable*, préférable par qui, pourquoi ? Des styles démodés, probablement, mais les modes, ça va, ça vient.

Comment: @jlliagre Je vois que nous n'avons pas été à la même école : nombreux ont été mes professeurs de français (primaire et secondaire) à corriger notre style en français ; d'ailleurs ce n'est pas une pratique désuète, il n'y a qu'à voir ce site pour le vérifier : https://robert-correcteur.lerobert.com/

Comment: @jlliagre Et surtout, chaque auteur doit bien évidemment être libre de son style. Cette liberté, d'écrire sans restriction (je souligne), il faut l'aller défendre à tout prix.

Comment: @jlliagre  *D’amour mourir me font, belle Marquise, vos beaux yeux. Ou bien : Vos yeux beaux d’amour me font, belle Marquise, mourir. Ou bien : Mourir vos beaux yeux, belle Marquise, d’amour me font. Ou bien : Me font vos yeux beaux mourir, belle Marquise, d’amour.*

Comment: @Frank Définition de style dans *Le Robert* « Part de l'expression (notamment écrite) qui est laissée à la liberté de chacun, n'est pas directement imposée par les normes, les règles de l'usage, de la langue. ».

Comment: @None Oh, mais tu fais de la _prose_!

Comment: @LPH Les enseignants sont dans leur rôle pour assister les élèves qui ont du mal à s'exprimer clairement à l'écrit et les aider à améliorer leurs rédactions mais je ne crois pas que *Messieurs les Ronds-de-Cuir* corresponde de près ou de loin à cette situation.

Comment: La plupart des manuels scolaires indiquent que le complément du nom y est accolé et "normalement non déplaçable". Bien sûr, toute la subtilité est dans ce "normalement"... Il semble utile de distinguer la notion de style dans le contexte normatif de l'apprentissage scolaire et dans celui d'une oeuvre littéraire.

Answer (score 1):

En fait, cette virgule est intéressante, et pourrait être utilisée même de nos jours, car en cassant le flot de la phrase, elle donne une impression plus vivante d'un Letondu qui bougonne tout seul dans son coin là-bas sur divers sujets touchant les *turpitudes humaines* sans beaucoup de rime ni de raison.